# Acute triangle on sphere

Tags: combinations, triangles, spherical-trigonometry

In excersise 3.7 from Geometry and Topology by Reid M. and Szendroi B. they ask me to prove that $(p,q,r)$ must have a specific form when you have an acute angled spherical triangle whose angles are submultiples of $\frac{\pi}{p}, \frac{\pi}{q}, \frac{\pi}{r}$.

I cannot find what an acute angle means on a sphere. Is it still that no angle can be more than **or equal to** $\frac{\pi}{2}$? Because the possibilities for $(p,q,r)$ all have $2$ in their answers, which would mean right angles on a normal triangle (**so not acute as the question states**), and so now I'm assuming that on spheres it works the same.

Using the **hint** at the bottom of the excersise and using that the area of a triangle must be greater than 0 gives me that expression, and from there on it's easy to get the triples $(p,q,r)$ for which this holds.

"
[image]
"

Comment: What does "submultiple" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not mentioned in the book besides here so I had to look it up as well: "a number that can be divided exactly into a specified number." So basically division without remainder I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're using the same word to describe a right triangle in ordinary Euclidean geometry... just replace the word "acute" by "non-obtuse" and move on. It's a bad choice of words, but the meaning is clear. Right angles are allowed in this one.